# Multiple Modal Opening when Updating a Row using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-bootstrap

I created a project using React and Bootstrap Table. Opening of modal is functional but unfortunately all the data in the table also opens their own modal.

So example I have 5 data in the table, when updating a row, the other four (4) modal also rendered and display.

The id of the data from Firestore is accessible to the child component (Edit_Modal.tsx) is there a way to add an id for the modal to make a reference to the data?

**Manuscript.jsx**

```
              <tbody>
                {thesisData.map((doc, index) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={doc.id}>
                      <td>{index + 1}</td>
                      <td>{doc.title}</td>
                      <td>
                        {doc.members[0]}, {doc?.members[1]}
                      </td>
                      <td>{doc.adviser}</td>
                      <td>{doc.course}</td>
                      <td>{doc.pages}</td>
                      <td className="m-1 text-center">
                        <Button
                          className="mb-1"
                          variant="secondary"
                          onClick={(e) => openUpdateModal(doc.id, e)}
                        >
                          <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                            <div>
                              <BsFillPencilFill />
                            </div>
                          </IconContext.Provider>
                          {showModalEdit && <Edit_Modal modalToggle={doc.id} />}
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                          className="mb-1"
                          variant="danger"
                          onClick={(e) => deleteHandler(doc.id)}
                        >
                          <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                            <div>
                              <BsFillTrashFill />
                            </div>
                          </IconContext.Provider>
                        </Button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
              </tbody>
```

**openUpdateModal() function**

```
  const openUpdateModal = (id) => {
    setThesisId(id);
    setShowModalEdit(true);
  };
```

**Edit_Modal.tsx**

```
const Edit_Modal = ({ modalToggle }) => {
  //Use States for Modal
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);


  const handleClose = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

 return ReactDom.createPortal(
    <div>
      <Modal
        show={show}
        keyboard={false}
        onHide={handleClose}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            Update Thesis Details
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form
            noValidate
            validated={validated}
            id="addFormId"
            onSubmit={handleUpdateForm}
          >
            <Row className="mb-3">
              <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridTitle">
                <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                  placeholder="Enter title"
                  value={title}
                  required
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                  Please enter a title.
                </Form.Control.Feedback>
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridAdviser">
                <Form.Label>Adviser</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e) => setAdviser(e.target.value)}
                  placeholder="Name of Adviser"
                  value={adviser}
                  required
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                  Please enter an Adviser.
                </Form.Control.Feedback>
              </Form.Group>
            </Row>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAbstract">
              <Form.Label>Abstract</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                as="textarea"
                onChange={(e) => setAbstract(e.target.value)}
                rows={3}
                placeholder="Enter Abstract Details"
                value={abstract}
                required
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                Please enter Abstract Details.
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
            <Button type="Submit">Add Content</Button>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("modal-root")
  );
};

export default Edit_Modal;
```

Comment: {showModalEdit && <Edit_Modal modalToggle={doc.id} />}. this line should not be placed inside the button which in turn is inside the loop. This should be kept outside the loop. since it is a modal. you can either place this line before the tbody or after the tbody

Comment: Since you are also setting => setThesisId(id);, you can use this value to pass in the props

Comment: @adhinarayan how can access the doc.id because the coverage of the code is from the inside of tbody

Comment: const openUpdateModal = (id) => {
    setThesisId(id);
    setShowModalEdit(true);
  };

I beleieve you have a variable for thesis id. you could you this variable to pass the props

Comment: Could you post the entire code for those two files if it is possible. I will be able to help you out better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @adhinarayan said you can use the useState of setThesisId to get the specific ID of your document.

Example useState:

```
const [thesisId, setThesisId] = useState("");
```

You can use the openUpdateModal function to get the Modal and the thesis ID

```
      const openUpdateModal = (id) => {
        setThesisId(id); //useState for ID
        setShowModalEdit(true); //useState for Modal
};
```

Finally, make sure that the Modal Component was placed outside of the map function to avoid looping of modals. You can set the thesisId to customized props of Edit_Modal

```
             ...</tbody>
        </Table>
        {showModalEdit && <Edit_Modal modalToggle={thesisId} />}
      </Col>...
```